# Macros/define in Python

Tags: python

I don't know if it feasable but I would like to do define a macro (Not a function because it will add some cost to the execution) only to make my code more readable and reusable. This is an example of something i want to do. I want substract(num) and add(num) to be macros

```
substract(num):
if num>1:
  print(num-1)
else
  print(num)

add(num):
  print(num+1)

main:
  word = 'hello'
  if  word == 'bye':
    add(1)
    substract(2)
  elif  word == 'hi':
    substract(3)
    add(2)
...
```

Comment: Python does not have macros. You can use an external tool like `m4` to preprocess a file to *produce* Python source code.

Comment: How much overhead do you think this would add, and what is your basis for thinking so?

Comment: [Macropy](https://macropy3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) adds macros via import hooks and similar metaprogramming. It's probably a good idea to read their [discussion of "magic"](https://macropy3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discussion.html#discussion) to gauge whether using macros is actually something one should do.

Comment: There is, however, a [draft PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0638/) to *add* macros. I do not know how close it is to being accepted or rejected, though. (It currently mentions there is no reference implementation, which means it's basically just an idea at this point, not something that anyone has a working demo of.)